# Prism RegionManager: how to navigate from a current view?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In order to load a Prism Module's view to a WPF application Region

```
<ContentControl Name="MainRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
```

I can use `regionManager.RequestNavigate`:

```
this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, toViewUri);
```

Sometimes I need to just remove the Module's view from the `MainRegion` (clear everything). If I do it by `this.MainRegion.Content = null;` then all is okay, except I cannot navigate to the previous view until I navigate to some other one.

**How to correctly navigate from a current view without navigating to any other view?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried either of these?

```
regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentRegion].Remove(view)
regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainContentRegion].Deactivate(view)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`IRegion.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iregion.remove%28v=pandp.40%29) does exactly that.